# How to run sudo mn --custom option in Mininet?

Tags: python, mininet

I am trying to run .py script in Mininet with --custom option. My code is as follows:

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.util import dumpNodeConnections
from mininet.log import setLogLevel
from mininet.util import irange

class LinearTopo( Topo ):
    "Linear topology of k switches, with n hosts per switch."

    def build( self, k=2, n=1, **_opts):
        """k: number of switches
           n: number of hosts per switch"""
        self.k = k
        self.n = n

        if n == 1:
            genHostName = lambda i, j: 'h%s' % i
        else:
            genHostName = lambda i, j: 'h%ss%d' % ( j, i )

        lastSwitch = None
        for i in irange( 1, k ):
            # Add switch
            switch = self.addSwitch( 's%s' % i )
            # Add hosts to switch
            for j in irange( 1, n ):
                host = self.addHost( genHostName( i, j ) )
                self.addLink( host, switch )
            # Connect switch to previous
            if lastSwitch:
                self.addLink( switch, lastSwitch )
            lastSwitch = switch


def simpleTest():
        "Create and test a simple network"
        topo = LinearTopo(k=4,n=8)
        net = Mininet(topo)
        net.start()
        print "Dumping host connections"
        dumpNodeConnections(net.hosts)
        print "Testing network connectivity"
        net.pingAll()
        net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
        # Tell mininet to print useful information
        setLogLevel('info')
        simpleTest()
```

When i try:

```
sudo mn --custom topo.py --topo LinearTopo
```

i get the following error:

```
*** Cleanup complete.
mininet@mininet-vm:~$ sudo mn --custom topo.py --topo LinearTopo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Caught exception. Cleaning up...

Exception: Invalid topo name LinearTopo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** Removing excess controllers/ofprotocols/ofdatapaths/pings/noxes
killall controller ofprotocol ofdatapath ping nox_core lt-nox_core ovs-openflowd ovs-controller udpbwtest mnexec ivs 2> /dev/null
killall -9 controller ofprotocol ofdatapath ping nox_core lt-nox_core ovs-openflowd ovs-controller udpbwtest mnexec ivs 2> /dev/null
pkill -9 -f "sudo mnexec"
*** Removing junk from /tmp
rm -f /tmp/vconn* /tmp/vlogs* /tmp/*.out /tmp/*.log
*** Removing old X11 tunnels
*** Removing excess kernel datapaths
ps ax | egrep -o 'dp[0-9]+' | sed 's/dp/nl:/'
***  Removing OVS datapaths
ovs-vsctl --timeout=1 list-br
ovs-vsctl --timeout=1 list-br
*** Removing all links of the pattern foo-ethX
ip link show | egrep -o '([-_.[:alnum:]]+-eth[[:digit:]]+)'
ip link show
*** Killing stale mininet node processes
pkill -9 -f mininet:
*** Shutting down stale tunnels
pkill -9 -f Tunnel=Ethernet
pkill -9 -f .ssh/mn
rm -f ~/.ssh/mn/*
*** Cleanup complete.
```

Could you please tell me why a get error: Invalid topo name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add line before `def` there should not be indent

```
TOPOS = {'LinearTopo' : (lambda : LinearTopo())}
```

Now you can execute

```
sudo mn --custom topo.py --topo LinearTopo
```

The above program you had written can be directly execute using

```
sudo python <file_name>.py
```

If you need to run using `sudo mn` with values, update the code as shown belown

```
 TOPOS = {'LinearTopo' : (lambda : LinearTopo(4,5))}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Karthik!

Comment: I have one more question. Would you maybe know why the topology ads only k=2 switches and n=1 host instead of k=4 switches and n=8 hosts as it is specified in def simpleTest()? I tried adding TOPOS before and after def simpleTest() but the result is the same.